# How can I transform a mapped BAM file into an unmapped BAM file?

Tags: sam, read-mapping, software-recommendation

In order to use [MergeBamAlignment (Picard)](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/current/picard_sam_MergeBamAlignment.php), I need an unmapped BAM file and a mapped BAM file. I have two mapped BAM files:

- one with reads mapped to the reference I want but without metadata such as read group
- a second one with reads mapped to the incorrect reference but with metadata

When I try to use MergeBamAlignment with these two files, I get errors, such as "Second read from pair not found in unmapped bam". So I am trying to unmap the reads from my second BAM file. How can I do that? Is there a tool for it? Otherwise, I'll have to manually change the bitwise FLAGs, reference names, CIGARS, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need Picard's `RevertSam` operation (described in context [here](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/article?id=6484#optionB), manual [here](https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#RevertSam)).

```
java -jar picard.jar RevertSam \
     I=input.bam \
     O=reverted.bam
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use the bam with the metadata as the input to your aligner?  Maybe it will keep all those fields.

Comment: bwa mem requires a fastq file, it does not accept a BAM

Comment: Okay, I didn't know you had to use that.  You see that bwa aln will take a bam?

Comment: good point, the RevertSam worked though